# How to process a concatenated CSV file using cypher query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a concatenated csv file with a certain delimiter. Example:

```
name,age
John,24
Alice,25
--------
parent,child
Node1,Node2
Node3,Node4
```

So I want to process the first part of the csv in one query and the other part in different query. Is there a way to process this csv file according to the delimiter in Neo4j?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this in Cypher but it is cumbersome and inefficient.

Here's a snippet using [APOC](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/):

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///my.csv' AS line
WITH collect(line) AS lines
WITH lines, range(0, size(lines)) AS indexes
WITH apoc.coll.zip(lines, indexes) AS indexed
WITH indexed, [item IN indexed WHERE item[0][0] = "--------"][0][1] AS separator
WITH
  [item IN indexed WHERE item[1] < separator] AS first,
  [item IN indexed WHERE item[1] > separator] AS second
RETURN *
```

This gives:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"first"                                                  │"second"                                                            │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[[["name","age"],0],[["John","24"],1],[["Alice","25"],2]]│[[["parent","child"],4],[["Node1","Node2"],5],[["Node3","Node4"],6]]│
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

(One can probably also do this without APOC by e.g. using [`reduce`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce).)

With these collections returned, it is possible to `UNWIND` `first` or `second` and `CREATE` the related nodes. Still, it is going to be hard to read/write these queries and definitely slow to execute. So it's best to perform the split before loading the CSV using a scripting language (Bash, Python, etc.)